# What type of nmap scan is: -sS -T 5

Tags: nmap

Is there a name given to this specific type of nmap scan:

```
sudo nmap -sS -T 5 192.168.1.145
```

Is there a specific term/name?

Answer (score 2):

Manual to the rescue:

```
-sS (TCP SYN scan) .
    SYN scan is the default and most popular scan option for good reasons. [...]
    This technique is often referred to as half-open scanning [...]
```

`-T` is not relevant because it doesn't change how the scan works, but just adjusts the timing:

```
-T paranoid|sneaky|polite|normal|aggressive|insane (Set a timing template) .
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear - is it a specific "type" like we have a Xmas scan available

Comment: @pee2pee The manual calls it "SYN scan". "Xmas scan" is mentioned 2 lines down. _"-sS/sT/sA/sW/sM: TCP SYN/Connect()/ACK/Window/Maimon scans || -sU: UDP Scan || -sN/sF/sX: TCP Null, FIN, and Xmas scans"_